# Change onclick() function multiple times (background image change)

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, onclick

Have searched around for a bit trying to find an answer (and whether I can even do this).

I have some HTML and JavaScript that changes the background image based on whether the user is female or male.

By default, the page loads the male background and offers a button which calls bgChangeFemale() when clicked:

```
<img src="BackgroundMale.png" id="backgroundImage" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;"/>

<div id="gameContent">

    <div class="logo">

        <a id="genderButton" class="myButton" onclick="bgChangeFemale()" style="float:left; width:60px; height:10px; padding-top:5px; margin-top:10px; margin-left:0px; padding-left:12px; padding-right:30px;">Female?</a>

<script>            
 function bgChangeFemale() {
  document.getElementById("backgroundImage").src = "BackgroundFemale.png";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").innerHTML = "Male?";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").style.width = "40px";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").onclick = "bgChangeMale()";
}

 function bgChangeMale() {
  document.getElementById("backgroundImage").src = "BackgroundMale.png";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").innerHTML = "Female?";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").style.width = "60px";
  document.getElementById("genderButton").onclick = "bgChangeFemale()";
}
```

The first button/function works no problem at all and changes the background image to the female version. However, when I click the button again to change it back to Male, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or can this not be achieved?

Thanks for your answers (go easy please, first posting)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute isn't being changed. To change the onclick use this

For Female

```
document.getElementById("genderButton").setAttribute('onclick','bgChangeFemale()');
```

For Male-

```
  document.getElementById("genderButton").setAttribute('onclick','bgChangeMale()');
```

Comment: Always happy to help, please make sure you mark the question as answered to let others know who search for the same thing and for other developers/helpers know this question has been answered. Happy Coding :)